# Scrollbar issue with iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I have a iframe(https) within a div. The div(lightbox overlay) has overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden; which causes a vertical scroll bar to appear. the content of iframe is much bigger than the height of overlay and the overlay scroll bar doesn't scroll the whole iframe content.the iframe scrollbar is hidden by the overlay scrollbar.I want to scroll over the whole iframe content. I face this issue only in IE.
The overlay is used at many places so I cannot directly modify its styles.
Had anyone faced this kind of problem.
Please assist if anyone has any idea how to hide the overlay scrollbar in order to view the iframe scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this fixed by playing around with the styles.
I created a new style 'div.iframe-overlay' in css, which is same as the style 'div.overlay' but without overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;
Then toggle the class of div from 'overlay' to 'iframe-overlay' only for IE browser.
This helped the scroll bar to appear properly.